# IIS7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2 (VPS) - Error 400 on POST Request

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

I have a new VPS server running 2008 R2 and IIS 7.5.

Some client software (not browser) communicates with a server application (ASP.NET) via HTTP GET and POST requests.

On IIS7.5 the HTTP POST requests are rejected with the error: "HTTP Error 400 - Request is badly formed"

The same application works with no issues on IIS7 and has worked for years on IIS6.

I can only assume IIS7.5 does some additional validation checks?
Is there any way to turn them off? I tried all the settings I found on MSDN but nothing seems to work so far and I cannot even get IIS to dump a log for the rejected requests!

Changing the client code is not an option.

Below is the POST Request that fails.

Thank you,
Nikos.

```
POST /NK002/Inbound.ashx?rid=0 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: nkHTTP_1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: identity; application/octet-stream; application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: www.nks001.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 307

<nkXML>
  <header count="2">
    <service>Connection</service>
    <function>Initialize</function>
  </header>
  <body count="4">
    <platform>Windows</platform>
    <data>BbbFBwAAAABFPaRkAAAAAHN5aE8AAAAA</data>
    <attName_0>PoolRebel.Version</attName_0>
    <attValue_0>2</attValue_0>
  </body>
</nkXML>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `Accept-Encoding:` header. The last two Content-Codings are not valid:

```
application/octet-stream
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

According to IANA's permissiable Content-Coding values you can only use:

```
compress
deflate
exi
gzip
indentity
pack200-gzip
```

> [Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) Parameters - IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-parameters/http-parameters.xml)

IIS7.5 adhere's more rigorously to the standards than previous versions.

**Update:**

Further digging about produced this forum discussion:

> [Thread: IIS 7.5 Accept-Encoding fails with multiple values](http://forums.iis.net/p/1176719/1976075.aspx)

Comment: Thank you very much - that was the problem. I guess the only option is to update the client app. It will be painful but has to be done.

Comment: @Kev: any new insights on how to override this? Running into it w/ Google's PageSpeed service: http://serverfault.com/questions/588272/how-to-get-iis-to-accept-encoding-gzipgfe, nothing seems to work.